# Node couchbase module on Ubuntu server 12.04 throws "Invalid ELF header" error

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-12.04, npm, couchbase, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to install a node app with couchbase on an Ubuntu server.

I have downloaded Couchbase and installed it from here (as  listed on download page): http://packages.couchbase.com/releases/2.2.0/couchbase-server-enterprise_2.2.0_x86_64.deb

I can access it via web interface, it works fine.

Next, I try to install couchbase node module via npm:

```
npm install couchbase --save
```

This completes successfully. However when I try to run my app (which works fine on my desktop Ubuntu) I get this error:

```
ubuntu@aws-box:~/project/$ node index.js 

/home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:16
  throw e;
        ^
Error:   
/home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/couchbase/prebuilt/win/x64/couchbase_impl.node: invalid ELF header
at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
at require (module.js:373:17)
at bindings (/home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/couchbase/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:74:15)
at tryLoadBinding (/home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:13:31)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/project/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:30:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Someone suggested that because it is in prebuilt/win directcory, then NPM is installing the wrong package - but the directory structure is the same on my Ubuntu Desktop instance and its running ok. Could this have anything to do with AWS security groups?

Comment: It looks like there's a request for more info on this from [your posting][1] on Couchbase's site.


  [1]: http://www.couchbase.com/communities/q-and-a/node-couchbase-module-ubuntu-server-1204-throws-%E2%80%9Cinvalid-elf-header%E2%80%9D-error

Comment: Yes, I have replied... Will reinstall as soon as I can get to my computer

Comment: OK, after recommendations from my friends, my answer is: always use package manager (e.g. apt) or at least install from an RPM. I ended up installing Bitnami's Ubuntu 12.04+nodeJS instance on my AWS. Also, my friends have successfully installed on Ubuntu 12.04 using apt + npm.

Answer (score 0):

Those "prebuilt" folders are put there by the package author.  This is a package bug, not an npm bug.  Type `npm bugs couchbase` to go tell them.